# Private Information Retrieval and Writing at the same time possible?

Tags: pir

Are there any (possibly multiserver) private information retrieval (PIR) schemes that support private reads and writes (so called PIR Writing) *at the same time*, while having sublinear (in the database size) communication overhead?
The most recent, very efficient, PIR scheme I could find is the one based on [distributed point functions](https://www.iacr.org/archive/eurocrypt2014/84410245/84410245.pdf), but it seems to only support one operation at a time. That is, I can either outsource a database, where I have private reads or I can outsource a database, where I have private writes, but not both on one database. Preferably I am looking for something that is not based on heavy tools like FHE.

Comment: Is Oblivious RAM not suitable? There you have private reads and  writes at the same time.

Comment: No I'm specifically looking for something that is not ORAM. I need something that can run on an array/column of elements without enforcing some data structure on them. I was hoping linear (in the array length) computation time could buy me something :)

Comment: Generally PIR works by having each server store a copy of the database *in the clear.* As long as that's true, you can't have private writes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a single-server one: https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-3-642-13708-2_26.pdf

Obviously the data would need to be encrypted, otherwise it will be obvious what was changed, and the PIR-write protocol needs to somehow re-randomize the ciphertexts that were not modified.

Answer (score -1):

Check out the four-server ORAM scheme in this work (link attached).
The scheme does not use any complex data structure, but rather stores the data in a secret-shared and replicated plain array. It uses distributed point functions for both PIR and PIR-write, at the same time.

> The core idea behind the scheme is to apply DPFs not only for PIR, but also
>   for a variant of PIR-write. PIR-write, (a variant of which was first investigated
>   in [OS97]) is a cryptographic primitive that is the analog of PIR for a write-only,
>   rather than read-only, database. We use DPFs to construct a simple two-server
>   PIR-write where every server holds an additive share of the data. Our PIR-write
>   protocol is limited in the sense that the client can only modify an existing record
>   by some difference of his specification (rather than specifying the new value to
>   be written). However, if the client has the ability to read the record in a private
>   manner, then this limitation becomes irrelevant.
>   We combine the read-only PIR and the write-only PIR-write primitives to
>   obtain a four-server ORAM scheme that enables both private reads and writes.
>   In the setup, the client generates two additive shares of the initial data, X0
>   , X1
>   s.t. X = X0 ⊕ X1
>   , and replicates each of the shares. Each of the four shares
>   obtained is given to one of the servers. For a private read, the client retrieve each
>   of the shares X0
>   , X1
>   , using the DPF-based PIR protocol, with the two servers
>   that hold the share. For a private write, the proposed PIR-write protocol is
>   invoked with pairs of servers holding different shares of the data

https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.05145